# PMBudget identifier for syncronisation via API

Tags: acumatica

I am building a application to syncronise Project budget lines to a third party system via the API.

I am having an issue with project budgets in particular because the unique identifier is made up of ProjectId, ProjectTask, Account Group, InventoryId and CostCode.  There isnt just a one field sequence Id which im not sure why this table is designed like this?

The problem is I cant store this unique id in my other database because the user can change any of the fields that make up the unique identifier in Acumatica/MYOB Advanced website therefore it looses its link for any updates.

Has anybody ran into this or something similar before and how did you get around it?  My current solution I am thinking about is creating a custom field which defaults a Guid against it and using that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create your own GUID, you can use NoteID, that is unique:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that field but wasnt sure if that noteid field changes under any scenario.  Can you confirm that this field wont change under any circumstance, like if a user adds a note or deletes a note etc.

Comment: I believe it never changes, but I can't confirm it. We used NoteID in a project as an ID, so far it didn't cause any error.